# Как правильно скачивать файлы с удаленного сервера?

Tags: php

Как правильно скачивать статические файлы с удаленного сервера? 1 запуск скрипта = 1 скачивание файла, т.е keep-alive не рассматривается.

Какие я знаю способы:

1) Copy

2) fopen

3) file_get_contents

4) Curl

5) Библиотеки типа guzzle

Какие способы будут более правильные, а какие неправильные и главное - почему?

Для примера, превью ютуб видео https://img.youtube.com/vi/JMJXvsCLu6s/0.jpg

Comment: Смотря какие файлы, вы не могли бы уточнить?

Comment: @Theartofbeingalive уточнил. Но если есть какая либо разница, буду рад почитать про нее.

Comment: более правильными будут те, которые в наибольшей степени удовлетворяют задаче и не являются избыточными для ее решения.

Comment: @Pavel, Лично для меня Curl.

Comment: Используйте rsync

Comment: Т.е. как я понял минусов в функциях типа copy и file_get_contents нет?

Comment: обычно используют `file_get_contents` или `curl`.

Comment: `file_get_contents` - не знаю как обстоят сейчас дела, но в версии 5.6 была ошибка, если сервер возвращал `keep alive`, скрипт "зависал". https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/1490 Ну, вроде пофиксили.

Comment: Похоже что стоит провести сравнение всех этих методов и сделать сводную таблицу результатов тестирования.